# How to hide a div off the viewport responsively, and always showing the bottom 50px?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am looking for a way to move a div off screen (top up) and always keeping the bottom edge shown, say 50px.

Right now I have it set up to hide a percentage [90%] of the div using jQuery and CSS3. [jquery.transit is being used]. It is meant to be cross-browser supported. And it mostly is.

Now the issue is that the content inside is dynamic and changes the height of the div box. This results in weird transformations and the percentage being slightly off on different viewports [iPhone 4s - chrome Desktop browser]. Despite specifying min heights. The Div can not be static and must be responsive.

Maybe I am overlooking something small, but how would I go about fixing this issue so that it looks like the fiddle below. But without the static height.

HTML

```
<button id="left">&laquo;</button>
<button id="right">&raquo;</button>
<div class="block">
    <p id="text">Test</p>
</div>
```

JS

```
$( "#right" ).click(function() {
  $( ".block" ).animate({ "y": "-85%" }, "slow" );
});

$( "#left" ).click(function(){
  $( ".block" ).animate({ "y": "0%" }, "slow" );
});
```

CSS

```
body{
    100%
}
p{
    bottom:0;
    left:50%;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
}
.block {
    width: 100%;
    min-height:150px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: gray;
    z-index: 2;
}
#left {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:3;
}
#right {
    left:10%;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:3;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hw14kkoc/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can measure `.block` first, then subtract 50 off it, then move it. This example shows it working without the `min-height` on the `.block`:

https://jsfiddle.net/hw14kkoc/4/

```
$( "#right" ).click(function() {
  var y_delta = $(".block").height() - 50
  $( ".block" ).animate({ "y": "-" + y_delta + "px" }, "slow" );
});

$( "#left" ).click(function(){
  $( ".block" ).animate({ "y": "0px" }, "slow" );
});
```

This will allow for `.block` being any height and always move it up far enough such that just 50px remains visible.

Comment: This seems to work on most things. It's still buggy on iOS 7.1, but hey what isn't. Thanks again! I knew I was overlooking something.